# Query that will select the title of all the songs from the 'Pop' artists. It should use IN

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE artists (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    country TEXT,
    genre TEXT);

INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Taylor Swift", "US", "Pop");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Led Zeppelin", "US", "Hard rock");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("ABBA", "Sweden", "Disco");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Queen", "UK", "Rock");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Celine Dion", "Canada", "Pop");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Meatloaf", "US", "Hard rock");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Garth Brooks", "US", "Country");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Shania Twain", "Canada", "Country");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Rihanna", "US", "Pop");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Guns N' Roses", "US", "Hard rock");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Gloria Estefan", "US", "Pop");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Bob Marley", "Jamaica", "Reggae");

CREATE TABLE songs (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    artist TEXT,
    title TEXT);

INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Taylor Swift", "Shake it off");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Rihanna", "Stay");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Celine Dion", "My heart will go on");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Celine Dion", "A new day has come");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Shania Twain", "Party for two");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Gloria Estefan", "Conga");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Led Zeppelin", "Stairway to heaven");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("ABBA", "Mamma mia");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Queen", "Bicycle Race");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Queen", "Bohemian Rhapsody");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Guns N' Roses", "Don't cry");
    ~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

Проще писать так:

```
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title) VALUES
 ("ABBA", "Mamma mia"),
 ("Queen", "Bicycle Race"),
 ("Queen", "Bohemian Rhapsody"),
 ("Guns N' Roses", "Don't cry");
```

В последней строке использование `'` внутри `"` сбивает разум SQL )))

Comment: а задание как решать

Comment: задание нужно решать самому

Comment: я уже 3 дня периодически пробую решать не получается

Comment: если бы я мог не спросил бы

Comment: а за синтаксис спасибо